# eventlet on OS X?

Tags: python-3.x, eventlet

I'm not sure if Eventlet works on OS X because epolls doesn't support OS X.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inn
er
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "scraper.py", line 44, in thread_worker
    with eventlet.Timeout(60, False):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/timeout.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/timeout.py", line 66, in start
    self.timer = get_hub().schedule_call_global(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/__init__.py", line 117, in get_hub
    use_hub()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/__init__.py", line 71, in use_hub

    mod = get_default_hub()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/__init__.py", line 40, in get_default_hub
    return eventlet.hubs.epolls
AttributeError: module 'eventlet.hubs' has no attribute 'epolls'
```

Answer (score 3):

Eventlet is not platform-specific but its hubs can be. The `epolls` hub is only for Linux and it is Eventlet's default but you can change it. Check [Eventlet's hubs docs](https://eventlet.net/doc/hubs.html) to pick the right one for your situation & call `eventlet.hubs.use_hub` before performing any IO.

Example, using the platform-independent `selects` hub:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.hubs.use_hub("selects")
```